# SQL return list of courses with most recent date and next date

Tags: sql, date, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables in an SQL Database; 'course' and 'event', the course table has courseID (pk), coursecode and coursetitle fields. The event table has eventID (pk) courseID (fk), startdate, enddate.

I need to return a list of all the courses with a column showing the last date it happened, and the next date it is due to happen, using the startdate of the event table.

I can get the most recent date, or the next date of a particular course in the event table as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    startdate as nextdate    
FROM event

WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),startdate,112) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
    AND coursecode = 'acc01'

ORDER BY startdate ASC
```

I'd like the results to appear as follows:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| coursecode | coursetitle | lastevent  | lasteventid | nextevent  | nexteventid |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| acc01      | Access      | 2012-09-30 | 20127       | 2013-12-10 | 35612       | 
| wrd37      | Word        | 2013-11-02 | 34816       | NULL       | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

I need to show each coursecode once (courses are from different suppliers, therefore coursecode may not be a unique field, hence the courseid field). It is possible that the course doesn't have a past date, or a future date, or any dates at all. A Null is fine in the date/eventid fields for these because I will format them in the report design.

I hope I'm not repeating a question, but I haven't found anything on here so far.

Thank you all in advance for any help

Comment: what's the sql flavor?

Comment: @geomagas 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: Multiple `coursecode`s would also have multiple `coursetitle`s per `coursecode`. What's the criteria for the title choice?

Comment: @geomagas not quite sure what you mean, a coursetitle and coursecode combination should be unique, but there is a separate CourseID field in the table which is the primary key, this is what's used as the join. In the final output I may display CourseID, CourseCode and Coursetitle as the first 3 columns

Comment: Imagine the `(coursecode,coursetitle)` combinations `('acc01','Access foo')` and `('acc01','Access bar')`. If the query was to return `'acc01'` only once, which title would it choose?

Comment: @geomagas in my database, my `course` table is actually a temporary table which is already a distinct list of courses. It's arose from the complexity of the query required to filter our main list of courses and narrow it down to only the list we wanted to use, so for ease of use, and the fact that this list will be needed elsewhere in the future, we've created a temporary table with the list of courses we want to check. This table has a unique courseid primary key, so the `(courseid,coursecode,coursetitle)` combination is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH CourseCodeEvents AS
(   SELECT  c.CourseCode, e.EventID, e.StartDate, e.EndDate
    FROM    Course c
            INNER JOIN Event e
                ON e.CourseID = c.CourseID
), DistinctCourseCode AS
(   SELECT  DISTINCT CourseCode, CourseTitle
    FROM    Course
)
SELECT  c.CourseCode,
        c.CourseTitle,
        LastEvent = LastEvent.StartDate,
        LastEventID = LastEvent.EventID,
        NextEvent = NextEvent.StartDate,
        NextEventID = NextEvent.EventID
FROM    DistinctCourseCode c
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 EventID, StartDate, EndDate
            FROM    CourseCodeEvents e
            WHERE   e.CourseCode = c.CourseCode
            AND     e.StartDate > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            ORDER BY StartDate ASC
        ) NextEvent
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 EventID, StartDate, EndDate
            FROM    CourseCodeEvents e
            WHERE   e.CourseCode = c.CourseCode
            AND     e.StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            ORDER BY StartDate DESC
        ) LastEvent;
```

Note, I have also changed this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),startdate,112) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

To

```
StartDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Converting dates to varchars then comparing them is not an efficient way to remove the time element. Casting to `DATE` is much more efficient (if you have 2008+). For other methods in other versions of sql-server read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Comment: thank you very much, this appears to work although I haven't fully tested it yet. The reason for my messy date conversion is because date fields in our database are integers stored as eg `20131104` for today's date. I'm very new to SQL so the convert date string is probably my messy attempt so I could get a date to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what flavor of sql you are using, try something similar to:

```
;WITH cteEventsLast
AS
(
    SELECT e.CourseID, 
           MAX(e.StartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM Event e
    WHERE e.StartDate < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY e.CourseID
),

WITH cteEventsNext
AS
(
    SELECT e.CourseID, 
           MIN(e.StartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM Event e
    WHERE e.StartDate >= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY e.CourseID
)

SELECT c.CourseCode,
       c.CourseTitle,
       el.StartDate AS LastEvent,
       en.StartDate AS NextEvent
FROM Course c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     cteEventsLast el ON (el.CourseID = c.CourseID) LEFT OUTER JOIN
     cteEventsNext en ON (en.CourseID = c.CourseID)
```

this example uses common table expressions, which you can use for TSQL / MSSQL server. But depending on your SQL flavor you may need to use slightly different SQL

If you can't use CTEs than you could instead make cteEventsLast and cteEventsNext as subqueries in your FROM clause

I would also not use

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),startdate,112) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

to compare dates, as you have in your question. Instead just compare dates directly, i.e. like this

```
startdate > GETDATE()
```

Comment: The OP specifically requested for each `CourseCode` to appear only once.